# Resources not found, but only on seemingly random devices

Tags: android, resources

I'm getting quite a few crashes on a live app.

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Resource ID #0x7f080389
```

The resource exists. 
It is a PNG and it's set using.

```
icon.setImageResource(a.icon);
```

where a.icon is an int with the id of the image required. I'm 100% sure the value here is fine.

There is no obvious pattern in regard to device and operating system. With the same phone and os version in testing and most live users everything is fine.
The app is distributed on Play Store using a package. 
My current theory is that some people are getting the app via some other place (the app is not available everywhere) and the APK they are trying to use does not match the screen density of their phone.
Is this reasonable (and can I prevent this) or is there another possibility?
Cheers.

Comment: `... but only on seemingly random devices` I'd focus on "random devices".

Comment: I say random because sometimes it's Android 9.0, sometimes Android 6.0. sometimes A Pixel, sometimes an S8 etc etc . The app has been tested successfully with these combinations and more. Plenty of live users with the same combinations are fine.

Comment: So, it's not probably about "random devices", but more about some "random environment conditions" (i.e.: memory full, null pointers, ...). Something worth to investigate on, if you only had the crash logs from your users.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is coming because image is present but not for all the resolutions.
Device will check the image in all the drawable folders which are equal or lesser resolution to resolution of current device.
Various screen resolutions are mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi.
Example: if you image is present in drawable-xxhdpi folder and device is of resolution xhdpi. Then it will check for image only in drawable-xhdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi and default drawable folder and may result to resource not found exception.
Hence you should add image to all the various resolution folders as per the quality. xxxhdpi should have sharp and high quality images.
Also, it is recommended to add default images in the default drawable folder to avoid any resource not found exceptions.
Hope it helps.

Comment: What you say is correct if you upload an APK to the play store. All the assets are delivered to the user when they download, and the correct one used at run time. If you upload a package, the APK the user gets has only the resources they need, giving a smaller APK. My theory is that an APK from one device is being shared, rather then being downloaded from the store. There arent any memory problems, the app crahses on startup trying to get the first Image resource. The exact same code worked fine when the app was uploaded as an APK.

Answer (score 0):

Released the app as an APK. No issues at all. Definitely something not quite right with the package splitting.